# Will referencing weakSelf from within a method called by weakSelf cause a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, weak-references, retain-cycle

I think I understand how simple retain cycles are create but I don't fully understand more complicated situations.

Here is code that would cause a retain cycle. (right?)

```
[self.dataController loadInitialWithCompletion:^(BOOL dataChanged) {
    self.loading = NO;
}];
```

To avoid that retain cycle I would create a weak reference to `self`:

```
__weak typeof(self) welf = self;
[self.dataController loadInitialWithCompletion:^(BOOL dataChanged) {
    welf.loading = NO;
}];
```

I hope I'm correct so far.

Here's where it gets interesting. I have a method that calculates and caches text heights and then calls reloadData on a tableView. That method executes asynchronously and calls it's completionBlock (on the mainThread) when it's finished.

```
 __weak typeof(self) welf = self;
[self.dataController loadInitialWithCompletion:^(BOOL dataChanged) {
    [welf relayoutWithCompletion:^(CGPoint offsetBeforeReload) {
        welf.loading = NO;

        if (dataChanged) {
            [welf save];
        }

    }];
}];
```

Will this code cause a retain cycle because `welf` captures itself in the completionBlock for `relayoutWithCompletion:`? Am I correct in thinking that because welf is a weak reference I will avoid a retain cycle?

What if I took it a step further?

```
 __weak typeof(self) welf = self;
[self.dataController loadInitialWithCompletion:^(BOOL dataChanged) {
    [welf relayoutWithCompletion:^(CGPoint offsetBeforeReload) {

        if (offsetBeforeReload.y > 64) {
            [welf scrollToPoint:offsetBeforeReload completion:^{
                welf.loading = NO;
                [welf save];

            }];
        }

    }];
}];
```

It's welf all the way down...

Comment: I think these questions are similar but not the same, what about welf within welf thing? I don't store my blocks as properties etc.

Comment: If blocks are not stored as properties then it would be released after completion and retain cycle will be destroyed even if you use `self` in blocks (without weak self).

Comment: @Visput So my very first example won't cause a retain cycle?

Comment: If completion block is never stored (for example by property in dataController) then No. If to say more formally: it is retain cycle but it would be destroyed at the moment when completion block finished. So it's normal situation, it doesn't result to memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your weakSelf is a weak reference. Weak references do not cause retain cycles. That's the reason for using weak.